# MySQL Select one row with unique attribute value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building a stock keeping system and decided to store each product's balance (everytime it's updated) into the following table:

```
+------------+--------------+---------+------+
| Product_id | Warehouse_id | Balance | Date |
+------------+--------------+---------+------+
```

Example:

Staff adds 10 pieces to product_id 123 in warehouse_id 5

```
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| Product_id | Warehouse_id | Balance | Date        |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 123        | 5            | 10      | 2013-09-16  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
```

Staff then adds 3 pieces to product 234 in warehouse_id 5, and
5 pieces to 123 in warehouse_id 5,

```
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| Product_id | Warehouse_id | Balance | Date        |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 123        | 5            | 10      | 2013-09-16  |
| 234        | 5            | 3       | 2013-09-18  |
| 123        | 5            | 15      | 2013-09-21  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
```

*Notice the date column

Now let me add a few more rows

```
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| Product_id | Warehouse_id | Balance | Date        |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 123        | 5            | 10      | 2013-09-16  |
| 234        | 5            | 3       | 2013-09-18  |
| 123        | 5            | 15      | 2013-09-21  |
| 123        | 5            | 18      | 2013-09-24  |
| 234        | 5            | 10      | 2013-09-26  |
| 123        | 5            | 22      | 2013-09-29  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
```

---

How do i run a query that would get me all products' balances as at 25th of September 2013?

That means i need the following result:

```
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| Product_id | Warehouse_id | Balance | Date        |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 234        | 5            | 3       | 2013-09-18  |
| 123        | 5            | 18      | 2013-09-24  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
```

In short I need the latest row (by date), per product_id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that products' balances are being maintained per warehouse you can do it like this

```sql
SELECT t.product_id, t.warehouse_id, t.balance, t.date
  FROM table1 t JOIN 
(
  SELECT warehouse_id, product_id, MAX(date) date
    FROM table1
   WHERE date <= '2013-09-25'
   GROUP BY warehouse_id, product_id
) q
    ON t.warehouse_id = q.warehouse_id
   AND t.product_id = q.product_id
   AND t.date = q.date
```

Output:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | WAREHOUSE_ID | BALANCE |       DATE |
|------------|--------------|---------|------------|
|        234 |            5 |       3 | 2013-09-18 |
|        123 |            5 |      18 | 2013-09-24 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f49/30)** demo

Comment: why do you need to mention warehouse_id?

Comment: @Bere It may or may not be needed depending on how balances are being kept. OP is not clear in the question on this point. But it seems that and it's logical that they are being kept per warehouse.

Comment: @peterm, wow i completely forgot about mentioning that there could be multiple warehouse! Thanks for pointing that out. Query looks good, ill test it out at work!

Comment: @peterm, it worked great! Just one question though, the output in MySQL shows the following columns: product_id warehouse_id date balance warehouse_id product_id date, everything but balance is repeated?

Comment: @VivekManglani I'm glad I could help :) Now columns are repeated because of `SELECT *`. You should never use it production. Instead always specify exact columns you want to return as part of the resultset. `SELECT *` can be used for examples like this of for debugging though. I've updated the answer and sqlfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (PRODUCT_ID, DATE) IN
     (SELECT PRODUCT_ID, MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE
      WHERE DATE <= '2013-09-25'     
       GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID )
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f49/23)**

```
  SELECT *
  FROM table1 t 
  WHERE t.`Date` = (SELECT MAX(t2.`Date`)
                  FROM Table1 t2
                  WHERE t2.`Date` <= '2013-09-25'
                  AND t2.product_id = t.product_id)
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc645/1 Hi Justin..in this case it will give two results for one product..So I think you should add group by clause